# Processing File Directories

Tags: java, command-line, directory

I am writing a program which reads in files and then processes them. At the moment, I am using a BufferedReader to read in a list of files from a txt file. This txt file was generated in a command prompt from doing:

```
dir > filelist.txt
```

and then cropping down this to just the filenames.

I can incorporate this into my script by:

```
//pseudo code(needs further directory specification)
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();//pseudo code(needs further directory specification)
Process process = run.exec("dir > filelist.txt");
```

This command gives the directory with files in the form:

```
dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm       (filesize) file
```

Once I have this file I can run a Regex to extract the filename.

```
Pattern file = Pattern.compile("(\d){2}/(\d){2}/(\d){4}\s(\d){2}(:)(\d){2}\s(\d+)\s(.+)\.txt");

for (String fileline : filelist) {
    Matcher matchfile = file.matcher(fileline);
    if(matchfile.find()){
        filearray.add(matchfile.group().split("\\s")[3]);
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way to get just the file names from a directory within Java SE? This seems a bit long winded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list()` method

```
File f = new File("d:\\MyFolder");
String[] fileNames = f.list();
```

You can further **separate out the file and directories, using methods like**

```
isFile()
isDirectory()
```

**///////////////////Edited////////////////**

**Assume** i want to find out **whether this File object is a file or a directory...**

```
File f = new File("d:\\MyFolder");

if (f.isDirectory()) {

    System.out.println("Its a directory");
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your edit to include proper syntax for the two methods?

Answer (score 1):

With Java 7 you have the  *[nio.2 tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html)* , more complete and useful with *Paths* and *Files* classes

Answer (score 0):

Here you can get sample code to get list of files from a folder.

```
File file = new File("C:/MyFolder/");
    File[] files = file.listFiles();
    for(File f: files){
        System.out.println(f.getName());
    }
```

You can get more examples from http://java2novice.com/java-file-io-operations/file-list-from-folder/